# Homebrew not storing package under version name

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to use software that checks for installed versions of llvm by checking the names of the directories in `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/`. For some reason, my llvm 4.0 install (the one the software needs) in not located in `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/4*`, but `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/HEAD-7c44c2a_1`.

Here is the output of `brew info llvm`:

> llvm: stable 4.0.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
>   Next-gen compiler infrastructure
>   http://llvm.org/
>   /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.9.1 (2,040 files, 710.0MB)
>     Poured from bottle on 2017-01-12 at 15:35:04
>   /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/HEAD-e2cae83 (2,179 files, 873.6MB)
>     Built from source on 2017-01-12 at 16:29:06 with: --with-python
>   /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/HEAD-7c44c2a_1 (2,429 files, 1GB)
>     Built from source on 2017-06-19 at 17:06:14 with: --with-python

As you can see, 3.9.1 is exactly as expected, but the next installs use a git commit-based naming system.

Does anyone know how to instruct homebrew to install the package with its version number, or is there an easy way to just change the directory name and re-link everything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling all versions of LLVM and just reinstalling 4.0.0, which fixed it.